# Dynamically adding a row to a table using UJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have trouble with using UJS in my rails app. I need to add content to a table dynamically. The problem is, that even alert functions doesn't start. Here's a piece of code:
_form_index.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag create_path, remote: true do %>

              <%= text_field_tag :task_name, nil, { class: "textField", placeholder: "Start typing here to create a task...", style: "height:35px;font-size:20px" } %> 

              <%= hidden_field_tag :status, "uncompleted" %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag :project_name, project.name %>

              <%= submit_tag "Add Task", class: "btn btn-success buttonTask" %> 
 <% end %>
<!--- nested render --->
<table class = "table table-bordered table-hover">
        <%= render partial: "form_tasks", collection: project.tasks, as: :task %>
</table>
```

_form_tasks.html.erb

```
<tr class = "taskProp">
    <td class = "checkWidth" > 

        <%= check_box_tag task.id, task.id, false, class: "check" %> 

    </td>

    <td class = "textWidth"> <p class = "form-control-static textRender"> <%= task.name %> </p> </td>

    <td>
      <span>

        <%= link_to "", nil, remote: true, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-sort colorTask" %>

        <%= link_to "", edit_task_path(task), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil colorTask" %>

        <%= link_to "", task, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash colorTask" %>

      </span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then, if I submit form , create method is called from tasks_controller:
tasks_controller.rb

```
def create

    project_name = params[:project_name]
    project = Project.where( name: project_name ).take!
    @task = project.tasks.create( name: params[:task_name], status: params[:status], project_id: project_name )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to projects_path, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to projects_path }
      end
    end
  end
```

And at last thing that doesn't work.I don't think, I need AJAX for this part, cause multiple examples in the i-net use it without AJAX, like this http://bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/.
create.js.erb in tasks view! (Cause I'm doing a to do list and have project -> has_many tasks relation)

```
$(".table-hover").append("<%= escape_javascripts(render(partial: @task)) %>");
```

So the main problem is that ujs doesn't work at all.

Comment: Are you sure that the form submits correctly if you do it without the `remote: true`? I believe it should say `form_tag create_task_path`, for the create action to be called.

Comment: Yep, the form works correctly, without.create_path is reffering to create method in task controller.
create POST   /tasks/create(.:format)      tasks#create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking brain, I found a nice topic to solve my problem. The details are, that I had trouble with my javascript and one time my .js.erb didn't render.So here is some advice:

1. Read, what rails console says after you click some remote form or link etc. Check if the right file renders and if it renders at all, there can be errors( as in my case ).
2. Read this topic http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/ to find out, what's happening to your javascript.